# LogicApp:replace the message in the csv table with a "." for ","

Tags: replace, azure-logic-apps, logical-operators

I have the flow where i want to edit the column in the csv table and replace the "," by a "."

How do I do that? Because the replace function expression in logicApp does not return the column:

[image]

It asks me to take the complete body when I use the replace function.
Where as details column is available which I want to edit:

[image]

How should I replace the "," from the details column?

Answer (score 0):

For instance I've taken this as my sample .csv file which I'm retrieving from my storage account.

[image]

Firstly I have used Parse CSV file like you did the same, then initialised and used the `Append the string variable` connector taking the Productsname column. Lastly, have used the replace function expression to replace ' , ' with a ' . '.
NOTE: I have used '|' following productsname variable for future purpose.

Here is my Logic App workflow

[image]

**THE COMPOSE CONNECTOR EXPRESSION :-**

```
split(replace(variables('Productname'),',','.'),'|')
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Here is my workflow that you can refer to:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@split(replace(variables('Productname'),',','.'),'|')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each_2": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Productname",
                            "value": "@{items('For_each_2')?['Productname']}|"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_CSV')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_blob_content_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMjQwOCUyZlByb2R1Y3RzLmNzdg=='))}/content"
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMjQwOCUyZlByb2R1Y3RzLmNzdg==": "/container2408/Products.csv"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Productname",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_CSV": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_CSV": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "content": "@{base64(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))}",
                        "headers": "Productid,Productname"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['plumsail']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/flow/v1/Documents/jobs/ParseCsv"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<Your resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "plumsail": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subscription id >/resourceGroups/<Your resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/plumsail",
                    "connectionName": "plumsail",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/plumsail"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I did this then, Then i don't see the variable I initialize.
[image]

Comment: You cant initialise a variable inside for each loop , try initialising out of the loop and try setting it inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Hey Swetha thank you for your revert. what I did is I initialize the variable as a string. and then in the for each I set it. but its printing only same value for the complete csv

Comment: Apologies!! I have updated the answer. Can you please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I used items function express and did it directly.

```
@replace(item()?['details'],',','')
```

This was a bit strange it didn't work at first but now it is working.